# Not able to get Value in jquery from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value from the textbox on button click event but getting error as `function (a){ return p.access(this.function(a)` like this .Here is the code that i have written in HTML..

```
 <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-theme="b" data-transition="pop">Mobile</a>
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
 <form>
    <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <h3>Please Enter Mobile No.</h3>
        <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Mobile No.:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="Mobile" data-theme="a">
 <button type="submit" id="submitMobile" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery ..

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitMobile', function() {

alert("Add Phone Number here");

CallingNo=$('#un').text;

alert(CallingNo);
});
```

Please help me to correct this..Thanks ..

Comment: `.val()` instead if `.text` ?

Comment: and since button is of type submit .. use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: "The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea."  http://jsfiddle.net/cjrj9pck/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of text use .val()

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitMobile', function() {
   alert("Add Phone Number here");
   CallingNo=$('#un').val();
   alert(CallingNo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `value` property of the `input` using `val()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitMobile', function() {
    var callingNo = $('#un').val();
    alert(callingNo);
});
```